# Laravel how to remove index.php from url

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes

I've created an about page in Laravel and pointed it to routes, but the problem is when I go to the URL: `http://localhost:8080/bsms/public/about`
it doesn't work, and it says

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

However, `http://localhost:8080/bsms/public/index.php/about` is working fine. I want to my URL free from index!

These are my routes[image]

Comment: What are you using to server the site i.e. MAMP, WAMP, XAMPP, php's built-in server etc.?

Comment: @RossWilson I'm using xampp

Comment: You should have your public folder set as the web root for the project. Have a look at https://www.5balloons.info/install-laravel-5-7-xampp-windows/

Comment: can you share the directory structure

Answer (score 1):

go to /public/index.php
and add blow code after `define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));`

```
/*
 * redirecting addresses with /index.php/
 * */
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($url, '/index.php')) {
    $url = str_replace('/index.php', '', $url);
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you in localhost?

Try adding this line to your .htaccess file in your public folder:

```
RewriteBase /
```

So it should be like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If it doesn't work, try to give some more details about your project environment.

Also, url should be pointing to something like this:
bsms.test
or similar.

Comment: Ok, open console and type:
`php artisan serve`
Point to the url given, normally: 127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to access your about page through this url http://localhost:8080/bsms/about (taking in consideration that your view files are in resources folder and not in public folder).

Give it a try using these comands

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

And let us know how it goes.